# how to trigger a drag event on click of a button jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Im attempted to integrate an image cropping tool into my website.
Im using this http://www.trepmag.ch/z/jrac/example/

While it works perfectly on the example, unfortunately Im my own site it is not so smooth.

When I drag the box across the screen, it will not always update the co-ordinates unless I drag it a tiny bit more at the end.

My plan was to simply take the co-ordinates and send them to the server, but this is holding me up as its taking incorrect co-ordinates. Even if I drag the cropping area by another pixel it at the end it updates them correctly.

My thinking was to simply trigger an automatic drag of an insignificant amount (like .1px) to get the correct co-ordinates. However I have no idea how to trigger a drag event.

I was thinking of using `mousedown` but I still do not know how to tell it to drag.

Here is the plugin code itself 
http://www.trepmag.ch/z/jrac/jrac/jquery.jrac.js

EDIT: Here is the code of the event handling...

```
$('#output img').jrac({
  'crop_width': 250,
  'crop_height': 170,
  'crop_x': 100,
  'crop_y': 100,
  'image_width': 400,
  'viewport_onload': function() {
    alert('viewport loaded');
    var $viewport = this;
    var inputs = $('#coordinates').find('.coords input:text');
    var events = ['jrac_crop_x','jrac_crop_y','jrac_crop_width','jrac_crop_height','jrac_image_width','jrac_image_height'];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {

      var event_name = events[i];
      // Register an event with an element.
      $viewport.observator.register(event_name, inputs.eq(i));
      // Attach a handler to that event for the element.
      inputs.eq(i).bind(event_name, function(event, $viewport, value) {
        $(this).val(value);
      })
      // Attach a handler for the built-in jQuery change event, handler
      // which read user input and apply it to relevent viewport object.
      .change(event_name, function(event) {
        var event_name = event.data;
        $viewport.$image.scale_proportion_locked = $('#coordinates').find('.coords input:checkbox').is(':checked');
        $viewport.observator.set_property(event_name,$(this).val());
      });
    }
    $viewport.$container.append('<div>Image natual size: '
      +$viewport.$image.originalWidth+' x '
      +$viewport.$image.originalHeight+'</div>')
  }
})
// React on all viewport events.
.bind('jrac_events', function(event, $viewport) {
  var inputs = $('#coordinates').find('.coords input');
  inputs.css('background-color',($viewport.observator.crop_consistent())?'chartreuse':'salmon');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console for any messages?

Comment: I have , its not that its not working at all, its that it doesnt seem to respond as well, one reason may be because the functionality is loaded inside AJAX success on my site with a dynamically loaded image, whereas on that site is it loaded on the page load with a static image

Comment: To be able to help, we'll have to see your code.

Comment: Ok Ive added the code to handle the drag events

Comment: I resolved it, apologies, there was nothing someone could have done here, I had a transition property set on the entire div by accident which was causing the strange behaviour